# How to downgrade this node.js module to specific version and prevent automatic upgrade later?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemailer

I am using node.js Nodemailer module and encountered the following error;

> [Error: Unsupported configuration, downgrade Nodemailer to v0.7.1 or
>   see the migration guide
>   https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#migration-guide]

I looked at my package.json and realize that it is `"nodemailer": "^1.8.0",` version.

How do I downgrade to v0.7.1 and prevent automatic upgrade later when I run `npm update`?

Comment: see nodejs manual page - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: I think what you might want is npm shrinkwrap https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you need exactly v0.7.1, use `"nodemailer": "0.7.1"`, delete `nodemailer` under `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

Another way to do this is to run the command:

```
npm remove nodemailer
npm install nodemailer@0.7.1 --save
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. If I run `npm update`, will nodemailer be automatically upgraded? If yes, how can I prevent that?

Comment: No, because `npm update` respects the setting in package.json. If you used a caret or tilde then it may upgrade the package. Caret for major version, tilde for minor. "^0.7.1" would match anything under "1.0.0", "~0.7.1" would match anything from "0.7.0" to "0.7.9"

Comment: So, make sure it is `"nodemailer": "0.7.1"` and not `"nodemailer": "^0.7.1"`. Is this correct?

Comment: Re: "^1.1.1" vs "1.1.1"... [See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/4378314).

Answer (score -1):

use this command to install nodemailer with 0.7 version else it will give error while sending emails

```
npm install nodemailer@0.7.1 --save

var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
   service: "Gmail",
   auth: {
       user: "EMAIL",
       pass: "PASSWORD"
   }
});

var mail = {
    from: "FROM@gmail.com",
    to: "TO@gmail.com",
    subject: "Send Email Using Node.js",
    text: "Node.js New world for me",
    html: "<b>Node.js New world for me</b>"
}

smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
    }

    smtpTransport.close();
});
```